# Copy and move constructors

Tags: c++

Having following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class CIntPtr {
public:
    int* ptr;
public:
    CIntPtr() {
        // Default constructor
        cout << "Calling Default constructor\n";
        ptr = new int;
    }

    CIntPtr(const CIntPtr& obj) {
        // Copy Constructor
        // copy of object is created
        this->ptr = new int;
        // Deep copying
        cout << "Calling Copy constructor\n";
    }

    CIntPtr(CIntPtr&& obj) {
        // Move constructor
        // It will simply shift the resources,
        // without creating a copy.
        cout << "Calling Move constructor\n";
        this->ptr = obj.ptr;
        obj.ptr = NULL;
    }

    ~CIntPtr() {
        // Destructor
        cout << "Calling Destructor\n";
        delete ptr;
    }

};

CIntPtr returnCIntPtr(CIntPtr a) {
    *a.ptr += 2;
    return a;
}

int main() {

    CIntPtr foo;
    returnCIntPtr(foo);
    
    return 0;
}
```

there is both **copy** and **move** constructors called. Why is the move ctor also called? Shouldn't it only be the copy ctor called since we passing the *lvalue* as the f-ction param? When does the move ctor can be called in this code?

Comment: The function returns a value even if you ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

The move consturctor is called in the [return statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters) (i.e. `return a;`) of function `returnCIntPtr`.

> **Automatic move from local variables and parameters**
>
> If *expression* is a (possibly parenthesized) [id-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) that names a
> variable whose type is either
>
> - a non-volatile object type or
> - `a non-volatile rvalue reference to object type (since C++20)`
>
> and that variable is declared
>
> - in the body or
> - as a parameter of
>
> the innermost enclosing function or lambda expression,
>
> then [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) to select the constructor to use for initialization of the returned value `or, for co_return, to select the overload of promise.return_value() (since C++20)` is performed twice:
>
> - first as if *expression* were an rvalue expression (thus it may select the [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)), and
>
>   - if the first overload resolution failed or
> - then overload resolution is performed as usual, with expression considered as an lvalue (so it may select the [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)).

`a` will be tried to be copied to the return value as rvalue-expression firstly, then the move constructor is selected.

Comment: So the move constructor is called  in  `return a` line of `returnCIntPtr` function?

Comment: @Derek81 Yes, it is.